# A complete and simple example of a Named Update Operation

Tags: wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

Can anyone give me a link to a complete example of a Named Update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where to look for a named update, however it's pretty straightforward:

- Create a method on your DomainService (says it's named *MyCustUpdate*)that return `void` and accept on input an instance of your entity (says it's named *MyEntity*)and, eventually, other parameters (primitives like int, string etc)
- Decore this method with `[Update(UsingCustomMethod = true)]`
- Client side, on the generated entity *MyEntity* you'll find the method *MyCustUpdate*; just call it and when you're done with your edits, call `DomainContext.SubmitChanges`

Your custom update method will be called as part of your SubmitChanges call server side